# How to Make a Bar plot with in order items on the x axis in R Using ggplot2

Tags: r

I want to make bar plots using ggplot. in the x axis, I have 72 items. I would like to have the items in order from 1 to 72 but when I plot the data using the following commend, I do not get them in order like the attached plot.

```
p <-ggplot(data, aes(pos, log))
p +geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = group))
```

[image]
do you know how I can fix the plot?

Comment: What order do you get them in?

Answer (score 1):

'pos' is a character.  ggplot thinks it it putting it in the correct order.  If what you care about is the numbers, and not the trailing letters in 'pos', you could trim that variable and re-graph as follows:

```
pos = c('10g', '11t', '1a')
log <- c(3,4,5)
data <- (data.frame(pos, log))

data$pos.2 <- as.numeric(substr(data$pos,1,nchar(data$pos)-1)) 

p <- ggplot(data, aes(factor(pos.2), log))
p +geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem: you are getting a lexical order on the full spelling so "10G" comes before "1T" because "0" is before "T" in the ASCII sequencing. What you probably want (and are apparently having difficulty either recognizing or expressing clearly) is that you want these ordered primarily by their numeric component and only secondarily by their letter component. This sort of "mixed" sorting can be delivered with the `mixedsort`-function in the gtools-package:

```
library(gtools)  # possibly after installing the package
data$pos < factor(data$pos, levels=mixedsort(unique(dat$pos)) )
# then re-run your code
```